# Code model / Quotation mark (") in arg parameter

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

I try to create the next expression in codemodel(Sun):

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()=\""+whatToclick+"\"]/parent::span/parent::span")).click();
```

so whatToclick would be a parameter in my function.

So I wrote the next:

```
    method.body().invoke(JExpr.ref("driver"), "findElement").arg(jc.ref(By.class).staticInvoke("xpath").arg("//div[text()=\"+"+ whatToclick.name() +"+\"]/parent::span/parent::span")).invoke("click");
```

and I have two problems:

1. I don't success to put whatToClick as a parameter. It always in the quotation mark(Because my expression is a string, and I have to put `/"`, otherwise it close the string.)
2. The expression is created without the `click()` part.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead, which uses the the `JExpr.lit()` to reference Strings directly and `.add()` to concatenate the strings and variables.  Also it uses the `add()` method on the method body to add the `click()` invocation:

```
method.body().add(JExpr.ref("driver").invoke("findElement")
    .arg(codeModel.ref(By.class).staticInvoke("xpath")
        .arg(JExpr.lit("//div[text()=\"+").plus(whatToclick).plus(JExpr.lit("+\"]/parent::span/parent::span"))).invoke("click")));
```

outputs:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath((("//div[text()=\"+"+ whatToclick)+"+\"]/parent::span/parent::span")).click());
```